# git thinks files have changed

Tags: windows, git

I did some work on a project on one machine, then pushed to github and, on another machine, cloned and did some work, then pushed. Then I went back to the first machine and did a `pull`. Now the first machine thinks all the files that were in the project originally were changed. I've tried

```
git checkout -f --
```

and

```
git rm --cached -r .
git checkout -f
```

and even tried

```
git stash
```

but no matter what I do, `git status` tells me those files have been changed. How do I make it stop?

Comment: What's the file system you use underneath? This is relevant because FAT has less precision.

Comment: Did the files *actually* change? Perhaps you've got line-ending issues. Is the Github repository public so we can help?

Comment: Have you run `git diff` on any of the "changed" files?

Comment: NTFS. git diff says the whole file is different. and even if it's a line ending issue, shouldn't `checkout -f` fix that?

Comment: Like Greg said it's probably a line ending issue. `checkout -f` is *not* enough to fix that, unfortunately. After changes to the `core.autocrlf` setting you need to run `rm .git/index` and `git reset --hard` to make them effective. Note that the latter command will get rid of any uncommitted changes, so be sure your working tree is clean before you do that.

Comment: In my case, I've used Beyond Compare to diff the file in hex mode, and not a single byte is different. This is so very annoying.

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja I believe it happened the same way for me. Szeremi Attila's answer should work.

Comment: I tried that to no avail. I am beginning to think git really sucks :(

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja If you don't have changes you need, try deleting the entire local repo and re-cloning.

Comment: @Dan, unfortunately, I can't do that because I have some local branches that I don't want to push out. I keep my development in these before merging them into the master. The only solution I can think of is to commit the changes and then destroy the commit without putting the changes from the commit back into the tree. See [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266990/can-someone-explain-to-me-what-difference-git-diff-is-seeing-here)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a line-ending/autocrlf issue. A great trick I realized for fixing this (if your index doesn't matter) is:

```
$ git add -u .
$ git reset .
```