# Can someone explain to me what difference git diff is seeing here?

Tags: git, msysgit

I am using git on Windows 7 via msysgit. An issue that has been causing me a lot of grief lately is that as soon as I switch to certain branches, git thinks that some files have been changed and then I can do nothing to make it stop thinking those files have changed.

The steps to reproduce in my case (which might not be relevant to everybody) are as follows:

1. Checkout the master branch.
2. Checkout the pristine-3.7 branch.
3. Checkout the pristine-3.8 branch.
4. Checkout the pristine-3.9 branch.

At this point, git starts to assume that files have changed.

For example, here's a screenshot of a git diff output.

[image: git diff output]

Here's the diff output for the same file using Beyond Compare in Hex mode.

[image]

And finally, the git status output!

[image]

What's going on?

**Update to the question:**

A possible solution is to commit the changes locally and then to delete that commit *without putting the changes in the commit back into the working state*. How is that done?

Comment: If there is no obvious functional difference then just use `git checkout -- filename.x` to retrieve the "original" as it is stored in the repository.

Comment: I've tried that along with other suggested fixes, such as the `core.autocrlf` setting, the `core.filemode` setting, etc, hard resets & reverts. The only thing that sort of fixes it is committing those files. That is something I don't want to do (because I want those branches frozen). Reverting/resetting doesn't help. I've tried a `rm .git/index` followed by a `git reset --hard` as well.

Comment: The red blocks git diff shows are trailing whitespaces. This could have to do with CRLF. Im no expert on the matter but maybe this can help you.

Comment: That was my initial thought too. That's why I carried out the hex comparison (the middle screenshot). The hex comparison shows not even a single byte different between the 2 files.

Comment: use `git checkout filename` to get the old file back before the "changes". Have you checked the file permissions? do a `git ls-tree HEAD` and a `git ls-tree abc1234` and compare. (abc1234 should be replaced with the HEX from the previous commit)

Comment: I shall try that, but in the meantime, I have ditched git in favor of hg. It ended up costing me a couple of days so I decided not to continue with use of git anymore. I appreciate your help, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this problem constantly - the only thing that works is:

```
git rm --cached -r . > /dev/null # redirect if output is huge
git reset --hard
```

***but make sure you have no changes you want to keep***

See [git line endings - can't stash, reset and now can't rebase over spurious line endings commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122094/git-line-endings-cant-stash-reset-and-now-cant-rebase-over-spurious-line-en)

Someone must make a example repo that exhibits this behavior and post it to the git tracker - this is a bug (in the sense that `git reset --hard` and co should work immediately)

EDIT: make sure you have read the [required reading](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/) and set up a `.gitattributes` file

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer, though after months of pain and some lost work, I jumped ship to Mercurial, which I feel is better anyway, but this might be useful for others less fortunate than I am :)

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja: I should disagree with you here - git is ohh so awesome - but yes you will hit some snags - this is probably the one I do not fully understand. But one should try to produce a reproducible example and post a bug rather than run away. Git has features mercurial simply does not have - so one fine morning you'll miss it :)

Comment: As far as I can tell, it is Git that's lacking features, not Mercurial. What features do you have in mind?

Comment: @UmarFarooqKhawaja: can mercurial track the move of a function from one file to another ? Can you rebase interactively your branch ? Heck - I hear it does not have an index even :D

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [`autocrlf`](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) issue. In addition, you might have `smudge` and `clean` filters enabled with a custom implementation that is causing issues.

I'd suggest doing

```
git diff --raw master pristine-3.9 -- packages/fop-10/lib
git diff --raw pristine-3.7 pristine-3.9 -- packages/fop-10/lib
```

and inspecting the results. Rest assured that `git` does save the binary contents and the saved binary contents matches the SHA-1 of the tip of the branch. However, the binary contents may **not** match the **working directory** binary contents if you use some features (e.g. `autocrlf` or `smudge`). The `autocrlf` is more prone to cause issues for Windows users because Windows users still suffer from a historical Microsoft decision to use two byte code for a single line feed instead of a single byte code used in historical UNIX compatible systems and Machintosh OS.